# How to convert a string into hex value and get string back from hex value

Tags: ios, objective-c, int, hex, unsigned

I have a scenario where i want to convert a string into HexValue and fetch string from HexValue

For e.g i have a string with value '33' in it . So when i convert it to hex i get the result as '21' and when i convert '21' which is the hex value back to string i should get '33' back as the output.

Following is the code which i have done for converting string into hex

```
+ (NSString *) hexValue:(NSString *)str {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lX",
            (unsigned long)[str integerValue]];
}
```

so when i pass '33' to this method it returns '21' which is correct 
but the problem is i want to retrieve '33' back from '21'

Following is the code

```
+ (NSString *) unHexValue:(NSString *)str {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str];
}
```

but this does not return the expected value which is '33'. Instead it returns 21 only.

Comment: Look at the Unix section 3 library command strtol()

Comment: To handle this in Cocoa (rather than C library functions) look at `NSScanner`. HTH

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me and able to fetch same result.Hope it will help you.

```
 NSString *strHex = [self hexfromString:@"33"];
 NSString *newStr = [self stringFromHexString:strHex];
```

// Hex from String

```
- (NSString *)hexfromString:(NSString *)str
{
    NSUInteger len = [str length];
    unichar *chars = malloc(len * sizeof(unichar));
    [str getCharacters:chars];

    NSMutableString *hexString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < len; i++ )
    {
        // [hexString [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02x", chars[i]]]; /*previous input*/
        [hexString appendFormat:@"%02x", chars[i]]; /*EDITED PER COMMENT BELOW*/
    }
    free(chars);

    return hexString;
}
```

// string From HexString

```
- (NSString *)stringFromHexString:(NSString *)hexString {

        // The hex codes should all be two characters.
        if (([hexString length] % 2) != 0)
            return nil;

        NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString string];

        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [hexString length]; i += 2) {

            NSString *hex = [hexString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 2)];
            NSInteger decimalValue = 0;
            sscanf([hex UTF8String], "%x", &decimalValue);
            [string appendFormat:@"%c", decimalValue];
        }

        return string;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately your methods do not do what the OP is asking for - your code converts an arbitrary string into a hex representation of each UTF-16 character, the OP wishes to convert between decimal and hexadecimal numbers stored as strings. Also there are 4 hex digits per `unichar` not 2, so your code will fail for some characters.